# Yahoo Weather with JSON and Java

Tags: java, json, yahoo-weather-api

I want to create a software (with Java SE and JSON) to display information about Yahoo's forecast. 
I get the information [here (JSON format):](https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20weather.forecast%20where%20woeid%3D2502265&format=json)

Are there guides, articles, blogs, ... with example for my software?

I see the Yahoo Centre but is deprecrate (from 2007) and I can't find a valid guide!

Thanks! :-)

Comment: well, start coding something. jquery, javascript etc etc. Y! lang too

Comment: you may be able to trawl the nether parts of the web for that deprecrated thing :>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if you will be able to find detailed API documentation or step-by-step tutorial specifically for Yahoo Weather. A good place to start is the [YQL Console](https://developer.yahoo.com/yql/console/). Notice there is a `weather` category with a `weather.forecast` API test tool.

If you look closely at the URL you posted and the queries in the YQL test tool, they rely on something a `woeid` (where-on-earth identifier) parameter. You can utilize the [Yahoo WOEID Lookup](http://woeid.rosselliot.co.nz/lookup/vancouver%20%20bc) to determine the identifier of a particular location, to be input into your query. Hope that will help get you started. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks isim :-)  I want to study a simple step-by-step tutorial. I already know YQL (and its power). Have you got an idea? Bye!